# How to get Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<Object>>> from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to get something similar to;

```
CollectionReference _events = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('event');

Future<DocumentSnapshot<Event>> getEvent(String eventId) async {
    return _events
        .doc(eventId)
        .withConverter<Event>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Event.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (schedule, _) => schedule.toJson())
        .get();
  }
```

This function works when i need just one event from a specific user.
But i want it to return a list of Events. Something along the lines of the example below.

```
Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<Event>>> getAllUserEvents(String uid) async {
    return _events
        .withConverter<Event>(
            fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => Event.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
            toFirestore: (schedule, _) => schedule.toJson())
        .where('invited', arrayContainsAny: [uid]).get();
  }
```

Comment: Not sure I understand: `_events.doc(eventId)...get()` by definition returns a single document. If you don't want that single document, are you lookin for `_events....get()`?

Comment: Perhaps my question wasn't clear. I already use the first example to get a single Event, but i want a version where i can get a List of events that contains a users id in the invited array. 
If i use _events....get() i'll get a Future<QuerySnapshot<Event>> not a Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<Event>>>.

Comment: Keep in mind: we can't see your documents, and only know of them what you've shown us (which is very little). Returning `Future<DocumentSnapshot<List<Event>>>` means that you have a single document snapshot with a list of events. I'd expect `Future<List<DocumentSnapshot<Event>>>`, which is pretty much what a `QuerySnapshot<Event>` is.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.